# Object identity using sequence generator

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm using spring-boot with H2 DB and I did some code refactor.

On my old code base I have a Request entity which has an id that follows a DB sequence.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
public class RequestEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", length = 256, nullable = false)
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 10)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_SEQ")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "REFERENCE", length = 256, nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String reference;

}
```

In my new code base, I replaced the id by reference as the primary key of the table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
public class RequestEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "REFERENCE", length = 256, nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String reference;

}
```

Before if I created an entity and store it I would get the same object, as follows:

```
RequestEntity entity = createRequestEntity() -> RequestEntity@9876
requestRepository.save(entity) -> RequestEntity@9876
requestRepository.findAll() -> [RequestEntity@9876]
```

But with the new code I get:

```
RequestEntity entity = createRequestEntity() -> RequestEntity@1234
requestRepository.save(entity) -> RequestEntity@4568
requestRepository.findAll() -> [RequestEntity@4568]
```

As you can see, in the second example the save method seems to create a new object and persist it (RequestEntity@4568) which is different from the one created in the code (RequestEntity@1234)

Does anyone have an idea why the behavior has changed?

Comment: not sure whats the difference. Whats inside createRequestEntity method

Comment: so, is it persisting multiple object

Comment: @MaciejKowalski The different is the return of the save method. The createRequestEntity method just creates the requestEntity

Comment: @PavanKumarJorrigala it is only persisting one object, the requestEntity